# How to get the position of the first and the last tick mark in a Qslider?

Tags: qt, qt4, qslider

I want to draw a tick mark for a qslider in paintEvent, so I should get the exact position of each tick mark. As you know, the handle of slider takes some space, so the first tick mark does not sit at the left/top position of the slider, there is offset of several pixels. Same thing happens to the last tick mark which indicates the maximum value. I want to know how many pixels of the space? (On win and mac, the handle are not in the same width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not yet done so, download the Qt source code and copy how they do it. You will want to look in the various `Q...Style` classes, i.e `QMacStyle`, `QWindowsXPStyle`, etc. Some of the key calculations come from:

- QStyle::sliderPositionFromValue() method
- QStyle::pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_SliderTickmarkOffset, ...)

Look in the various `drawComplexControl` methods for `case CC_Slider:`, where slider controls are drawn. In the Qt 4.7 code, this starts on [line 2699 in qwindowsxpstyle.cpp](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/gui/styles/qwindowsxpstyle.cpp), for example.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this piece of advice helps me a lot.